# how to use pose model from teachable machines to simulate key stroke

Tags: javascript

// I think all you have to do is add a line and a library?

I am trying to use google's teachable machine to peek(left and right) in games, so how do i use the javascript code to simulate the keystrokes (hold the key till the the model predicts the respective class). I do not know javascript so i would like for you to add the line and library to this code so i can use it to simulate keystrokes.[This image to explain which key to add to what key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73RQL.jpg).
Lean right is with keystroke 'E'.
Lean left is with keystroke 'Q'.
Neutral (no  lean) is with none (not Q nor E) pressed.

```
<div>Teachable Machine Pose Model</div>
<button type="button" onclick="init()">Start</button>
<div><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></div>
<div id="label-container"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.3.1/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/pose@0.8/dist/teachablemachine-           pose.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// More API functions here:
// https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/pose

// the link to your model provided by Teachable Machine export panel
const URL = "./my_model/";
let model, webcam, ctx, labelContainer, maxPredictions;

async function init() {
    const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
    const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";

    // load the model and metadata
    // Refer to tmImage.loadFromFiles() in the API to support files from a file picker
    // Note: the pose library adds a tmPose object to your window (window.tmPose)
    model = await tmPose.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
    maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();

    // Convenience function to setup a webcam
    const size = 200;
    const flip = true; // whether to flip the webcam
    webcam = new tmPose.Webcam(size, size, flip); // width, height, flip
    await webcam.setup(); // request access to the webcam
    await webcam.play();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    // append/get elements to the DOM
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = size; canvas.height = size;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
    for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) { // and class labels
        labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    }
}

async function loop(timestamp) {
    webcam.update(); // update the webcam frame
    await predict();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

async function predict() {
    // Prediction #1: run input through posenet
    // estimatePose can take in an image, video or canvas html element
    const { pose, posenetOutput } = await model.estimatePose(webcam.canvas);
    // Prediction 2: run input through teachable machine classification model
    const prediction = await model.predict(posenetOutput);

    for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
        const classPrediction =
            prediction[i].className + ": " + prediction[i].probability.toFixed(2);
        labelContainer.childNodes[i].innerHTML = classPrediction;
    }

    // finally draw the poses
    drawPose(pose);
}

function drawPose(pose) {
    if (webcam.canvas) {
        ctx.drawImage(webcam.canvas, 0, 0);
        // draw the keypoints and skeleton
        if (pose) {
            const minPartConfidence = 0.5;
            tmPose.drawKeypoints(pose.keypoints, minPartConfidence, ctx);
            tmPose.drawSkeleton(pose.keypoints, minPartConfidence, ctx);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I am new to this, so tell me is you need more files/ details.